# Bootstrap background color disappears when opening in Windows 10 Edge or IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, windows-10, microsoft-edge

This is a Windows 10 Edge or Internet Explorer (IE) only problem. This works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Windows 7 IE.

Why bootstrap background-color disappears only in Windows 10 IE or Edge.

Is there something I can do to stop this from happening?

[JS Bin DEMO](https://jsbin.com/volayaf/edit?html,css,output)

**Windows 10 IE 11.0.10547.0**
[image: Windows 10 IE 11.0.10547.0]

**Windows 10 Edge 21.10547.0.0**
[image: Windows 10 Edge 21.10547.0.0]

Comment: Working fine on `edge` in system.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an ms Edge issue.
It's working fine in **Edge 13 - internal version 22**

Windows 10 build 10550

**It Works**

[image: It Works]

**This is IE 11.0.10550.0 Update 11.0.22**

[image]